# Insert image from a NAS drive to a PDF c# MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, itext7, c3.js, nas

I am trying to insert an image file that is stored on a NAS drive into a cell of a pdf created using itext7

When I go to use this code.

imagePath = "https:\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx\Jobs\Jobs\Quotes\12391\System\Plan.png";

```
            // Create a WebClient with credentials
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXXX", " XXXXXXX");


                img = new Image(ImageDataFactory
                .Create(@"https:\\\\202.180.99.51:5006\\Jobs\\Jobs\\Quotes\\12391\\System\\Plan.png"))
                .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                table.AddCell(new Cell(4, 2).Add(img));
            }
```

I get

IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'E:\source\AGBStone\AGBStone\AGBStone\https:\202.180.99.51:5006\Jobs\Jobs\Quotes\12391\System\Plan.png'

How do I stop it adding the local directory context and just use the URL i have entered?

This is a Web Appilcation in C# using MVC

Answer (score 0):

Added HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator to get past this error.